# Issue in Oracle Insert while Drop index and create after insert records

Tags: oracle

In oracle i did a insert in to big table contain more than million record.Before insert i drop a index on the table and insert it for a better performance and after insert i create a index for the table .But here is the issue,While creating index on table its shows me Unique constraint error,because it is vioating one of my unique index.Please advice how to proceed furthur.Since i dropped index and insert i am not able to check index while inserting records into table.

Thanks
venkat

Comment: Don't insert records that violate the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be remove the new offending row and create the index again.You'd be better off if you don't try to insert that row in database.